# Javascript type Error: Object doesn't have the method draw() when echoed in the error, it has the method?

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror

I have some code that is just supposed to iterate through an array and draw them to the screen in javascript.
However if the array is larger than one element i'm getting a type error, object has not method draw().
So naturally, I try to put it in a try catch block like so:

```
try{
                bulls[i].draw();
            }catch(e){
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(bulls[i]);
                console.log(e.message);
            }
```

now then, when I look in the console at bulls[i] and expand it, it shows:

```
bullet {paper: Paper, setSize: function, isShot: function, isShotToTrue: function, lineRemove: function…}
draw: function (){
getCoords: function (){
isShot: function (){
isShotToTrue: function (){
lineRemove: function (){
paper: Paper
set: function (nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2){
setColor: function (r, g, b){
setSize: function (s){
setSpeedX: function (x1, coords){
update: function (){
__proto__: bullet
```

as you can see, for bulls[i], draw is defined, but yet it claims it isn't? Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me? If you need more code or information please just ask!

EDIT: I put all the code on a JFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HxC6f/2/).
 to reproduce the error, you have to type person, then quickly ctrl+v in the word plant or animal. 
This wasy it will try to have 2 bullets on the screen. It doesn't fail with one bullet if you wait for the bullet to kill any of the words on screen before typing in the next one.

The classes are all in their individual files, in this case bullet.js it's added there in the constructor through:

```
this.draw = function(){
        lin = lin.draw();
        return this;   
}
```

I'll gladly give any other information you guys require.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle ?

Comment: Try echoing `bulls[i].draw` to make sure it wasn't added later, and the console updated.

Comment: Where is the method draw added to the object (where is it defined)?

Comment: +1 for the bullseye pun. And a cancelling -1 for not showing/explaining where and how the `draw()` method is added to the object, since that's likely where the problem lies. To expand on what Paul Draper said, some browsers log a live reference to an object such that when you later expand it it shows the current properties at the time of expansion and not the properties as they were at the time of the `console.log()` statement.

Comment: There we go, updated and included the JFiddle